# Connecting to zookeeper with Node.js

Tags: node.js, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to connect to a Zookeeper server using the [node-zookeeper-client](https://github.com/alexguan/node-zookeeper-client) library.

The code appears to work properly, except for one case which I cannot detect: when the server is not available and I start the client. In this case the client just hangs, without timeout (no events seem to be emited). How can I detect this situation?

```
var zookeeper = require("node-zookeeper-client");

console.log("connecting to zookeeper");

zk = new zookeeper.createClient("localhost:2181", {
        sessionTimeout: 10,
        spinDelay : 10,
        retries : 0
});

zk.on("connected", function () {
    console.log("connected");
});

zk.on("connectedReadOnly", function () {
    console.log("connected read-only");
});

zk.on("expired", function () {
    console.log("zk session expired");
});

zk.on("disconnected", function (){
    console.log("disconnected from zk");
});

zk.on('state', function (state) {
    console.log("state : %s", state);
});

zk.connect();
```

I'm aware that I could use something like this to detect the situation, but it feels like a hack.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    /* am I still in the DISCONNECTED state? */
    console.log("client state: %s", zk.getState());
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I tried different values for the `retries` parameter (as well as those timeouts), with the same result.

Comment: What versions of zookeeper and node-zookeeper-client do you have?

Comment: @mohit6up: node-zookeeper-client is `0.2.1`.  Zookeeper version is irrelevant since I'm testing the behaviour of node-zookeeper-client when a server isn't available.